# Puppet - How does node type work in ENC yaml format

Tags: module, puppet

I am very new to puppet and I am trying to work out how puppet is able to know what classes to apply.

I can see in `puppet.conf` that it is using an external node classifier which is a ruby script, all this script does is return the following yaml:

```
classes: 
- nodetypes
parameters: 
  nodetype: dev
```

When puppet runs it is running with:

```
puppet agent --onetime --no-daemonize --verbose --environment=dev
```

I would have expected in the `site.pp` file to see something like:

```
node myNode {
  include common
}
```

After searching the file system for files containing `dev` I have found that there is a puppet class that contains this:

```
class nodetypes::dev {
   include roles::dev_web_server
}
```

Can anyone explain how this is working? Specifically how the yaml value `nodetypes` and the parameter `nodetype` come together to form `nodetypes::dev` class which is then called by puppet to invoke the role of `dev_web_server`.

Comment: `nodetypes` designates a class name.  You will probably find it defined in a file named `notetypes/manifests/init.pp`, near where you found the `nodetypes::dev` class.  This is your missing piece.

Comment: How is it that the parameter `nodetype: dev` gets added to the class name? Does that mean its a parameterised class which takes a named parameter `nodetype` (in this case the value passed in `dev`)?

Comment: The parameter **does not** get added to the class name *per se*.  At least, not automatically.  The ENC directs that a class named exactly `nodetypes` be declared.  I told you already where to find that class.  I am confident you will discover that class `nodetypes` uses its `nodetype` parameter to choose another class to (additionally) declare, and that is where the declaration of `nodetypes::dev` comes from.  As I said, class `nodetypes` is your missing piece.

Comment: Yes the init.pp manifest declares inside it a nodetypes class which does take a parameter - $type = $::nodetype.It then looks like it uses that it to 'choose' (not sure how that works as it doesnt use include) an inner class class {"::nodetypes::${type}": }

Comment: There is no inner class there.  Rather, there is a *[declaration](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.4/lang_classes.html#declaring-classes)* of another (separate) class, using the resource-like syntax.  This is an alternative to using `include`, but not one that I normally recommend.  Ordinary Puppet variable interpolation is used to combine the value of class `nodetypes`'s parameter "type" with the static string `"::nodetypes::"` to form the name of the class to declare.  Inasmuch as none of this seems at all familiar to you, I urge you to read the current language guide.

Comment: Thanks I will read the language docs, you're right none of this is familiar at all, I work as a java developer but the project also includes all of the puppet source. I just completed a basic puppet course and then tried to work out what was happening. Unfortunately the course only focused on very simple puppet configuration and the project seems to be not very much like the way they taught puppet on the training course.